# dlopen() from sandbox in iOS 10 is blocked

Tags: ios10, dlopen

i'm using dlopen() to load dynamic framework from documents directory, it's working good below iOS10, but in iOS10 it does not work anymore，and console's log is:

```
file system sandbox blocked mmap() of '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/71EB4588-A83F-4AF0-9409-DD09AFB2CA77/Documents/MyDylib.framework/MyDylib'
```

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: I had this problem with Reveal 2.0 in conjunction with AppCode, which used to load it using DYLD. I had to add it via cocoapods (`pod 'Reveal-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']`) and then it worked. Hope this helps...

Comment: Have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

in iOS10 the framework cannot save to the Documents dir or subdir. you must put the framework under to the YouAppName.app/

Comment: With a source this would make a great answer.