# DLL(dylib) hot-reloading on iOS

Tags: c++, ios, dylib, dlopen

I'm testing dylib hot-reloading on iOS device.
(Here is some good reading on dll hot reloading. https://ourmachinery.com/post/dll-hot-reloading-in-theory-and-practice/)

It works fine on simulator as I can upload the dylib to app's document directory and dlopen() it.

```
std::string soPath = docPath + "/test.dylib";
auto h = dlopen( soPath.c_str(), RTLD_NOW );
```

But apparently this is forbidden on the device since iOS 10.

[dlopen() from sandbox in iOS 10 is blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461798/dlopen-from-sandbox-in-ios-10-is-blocked)
https://gist.github.com/jonbro/0638a2056e134bc26498

dlopen() returns NULL and dlerror() gives me same error with above links.

> file system sandbox blocked mmap() of '...'

On Android it also refuse to dlopen() a .so file in 'external storage' but it's permitted in 'internal storage'.
There with app's file write permission I think I can automate the process using local file server.

Is there this type of storage/directory on iOS where I can upload a dylib file and dlopen() it?
Or any kind of workaround?

I would prefer not to jailbreak.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Keep in mind that section 2.5.2 of the App Store Review Guidelines prohibits iOS apps from downloading code.

Comment: @duskwuff Productivity. I'm developing my own game engine and thinking about eliminating script language if dll hot reloading is viable option, just like unreal engine 4.  I have no intention to ship dylib in final product, it will be built as monolithic with static version of modules. But in development if I can modify code and apply it while my game is still running, it's huge gain of efficiency (and main reason of using script language in game engine).

Comment: @visor24 Develop it under macOS and deploy under iOS, without the hot-reloading functionality.

Comment: @trojanfoe I know it will work on my development PC, Android and even iOS simulator, but it's always good to have the functionality in the real device. It seemed there is no clean way to do so but I kind of wanted to confirm if it's really that case.